# How to spot a regex that contains escape characters?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text (string):
`System.out.println(text)`

```
..............
BLOOMINGTON, IL  61710
Page 4 of 5
8/2/2009file://C:\hjO Fhjes\hShjort_2012w211231_0323212_575.htm
Location: EAST JEFRYN, NY
..............
```

---

I need to get rid of any substring that starts with the word `"Page"` and ends with `".htm"`

I tried the following:

```
      Pattern patternP = Pattern.compile("(?:Page.*?)(\\n+)+htm", Pattern.DOTALL);
      Matcher matcherP = patternP.matcher(filtered);
      matcherP.find();
      String page = matcherP.group();
      text = text.replace(page, "");
```

But this does not filter, i think because of the escape characters. How can i improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't allow for any of the content between the `\n` and the `htm`.  you might want to change it to

```
"(?:Page.*?)(\n+).+htm"
```

take note that I only used 1 `\` to escape the newline.  That's because `\n` is a java escape sequence, you only need to use 2 `\` for regex escape sequences like `\\d`

*you might need to make sure that your regex implementation supports newlines like that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is because your regex is wrong. Try this regex for your match:

```
Pattern.compile("Page(.+?)\\.htm", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

You can just call `String#replaceFirst` to do this in one call:

```
String repl = filtered.replaceFirst("(?s)Page(.+?)\\.htm", "");
```

Where `(?s)` acts as `Pattern.DOTALL`

Comment: Thank you for reply. But this does not work. Also, why is my regex wrong?